# Backbone ignoring idAttribute and setting its own

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Im creating new models from an API, the API has an idAttribute **ID**. This is my model:

```
class Video extends Backbone.Model
    idAttribute: 'ID'   
    urlRoot: inbox.api.url + "/program"
```

Collection:

```
class Videos extends Backbone.Collection
    model = Video
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'inbox.video'
    url: inbox.api.url + "/program"
```

Here Im adding models to the Collection:

```
_.each data, (o) =>

        model = collection.get o.ID
        if model != undefined
            model.set o
        else
            collection.create o
```

The problem is that the id of the model created is NOT the ID in the data returned so creating a model each time because it does not find the model when looking for o.ID

This is **o** on one of the itterations:

```
ChannelID: "b5f52a36-b154-4232-ace0-4075c384bee1"
ID: "10fa83a6-8508-40a3-a901-a40cad2041da"
LastWriteUTC: "2013/08/19 02:51:14 PM"
Name: "Moments_of_Everyday_Life.mp4"
Publisher: "Marthin"
Size: 1043200
```

Why is the model's id attribute not set to the correct ID?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem probably is that at the point where the `model = Video` is being evaluated it is not yet defined. Try assigning the model in the initialize method

For example

```
var  Videos = Backbone.Collections.extend({

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('inbox.video'),
    url: inbox.api.url + "/program",

    initialize: function () {
      this.model = Video;
    }
})
```

Comment: That will work but you missed the CoffeeScript syntax problem that is at the root of things.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
class Videos extends Backbone.Collection
  model = Video
```

That `model = Video` does not set the collection's `model` property to `Video`, it merely creates a private class variable of sorts. If you look at the generated JavaScript you'll see something like this:

```
var Videos = (function(_super) {
  var model;
  //...
  model = Video;

  return Videos;

})(Backbone.Collection);
```

If you were creating a `model` property, you'd see:

```
Video.prototype.model = Video;
```

instead. So there won't be a `model` property on instances of `Videos` and Backbone will use the default `Backbone.Model` and that has `idAttribute: 'id'`.

You probably want to say this:

```
class Videos extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Video
```

The colon will get you the `Videos::model` that you're expecting.

Have a look at a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2KNM6/):

```
class M extends Backbone.Model

class C1 extends Backbone.Collection
    model = M

class C2 extends Backbone.Collection
    model: M

console.log(C1::model)
console.log(C2::model)
```

and you'll see the difference, `C1::model` will be `Backbone.Model` but `C2::model` will be `M`.